# how to use aggregate in drupal 8 for count?

Tags: aggregate, drupal-8

So I have a table which counts all the word that is searched in the website. and I have to view the result, order by the counts in the table for that word.

how to use the aggregate function in views(Drupal 8) for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you open edit form for your view, in 3rd column "Advanced" you will see: "
Use aggregation: NO". You need to set "Yes". And after it you will see aggregation settings for all your fields in view. 
It means that you can use aggregation functions in query. (eg. SUM)

PS: And I dont' fully undestand your question. You asked "how to use" or "should I use". 
For 1st question I've answered below.
For 2nd question: it depends on how you're storing it in DB.
If you are storing word => total count, I think you don't need aggregation, if you create new row for every time when user search by some word, you will need aggregation in your view.

Comment: Sorry the question is edited :) . So, yes i am storing in DB as word -> count. so i need to match the data searched or the result which is LIKE or equal to word stored in table and order by count of that word